# Package-relative identifier path in Java

Tags: java, namespaces, package, project

### Introduction

Moving from C++, one of the big differences was the difference in scoping: In C++ every identifier is relative to the current scope (`class` or `namespace`) and you could write an absolute path with the scope resolution operator `::` in the beginning.

However, in Java I could not find a way to access to an identifier from other package without importing it to the current scope or writing its full path.

It could be a problem if I have a few classes with the same name (then, in C++ I would address them as Module1::Foo and Module2::Foo, which is not possible in Java as long as I want to save my sanity since `com.company.project.module1.Foo` is too long for my taste).

### Code!

Here's an example for accessing the class `Tools.Useless.Foo` from Java and C++ (with no `import` or `using`)

`Tools/Useless/Foo.hpp`:

```
namespace Tools {
namespace Useless {
class Foo {         
};
}
}
```

`Tools/Bar.hpp`

```
namespace Tools {
...
// Use Foo with a relative identifier
Useless::Foo foo;
// Use Foo with an absolute identifier.
::Tools::Useless::Foo bar;
...
}
```

And that's how it would look in Java:

`com/company/project/Tools/Useless/Foo.java`:

```
package com.company.project.Tools.Useless;

public class Foo { }
```

`com/company/project/Tools/Bar.java`:

```
...
// Use Foo with a relative identifier
???
// Use Foo with an absolute identifier.
com.company.project.Tools.Useless.Foo foo;
...
```

### The question(s)

1. Is there a way to access `Foo` from package `Tools.Useless` without specifying `Tools.Useless` full package name (and importing it; since importing it will bind it to the current scope)?
2. Am I doing it right? How should I use a few classes with the same name? Should I just avoid that or just import them with "package.*" to bypass it?

### Solutions

1. Using more package-descriptive class names (e.g. `ToolsUselessFoo` instead of just `Foo`).
2. Importing everything with `import path.to.module.*` instead of `import path.to.module.Foo` and then access `Foo` the the needed packages to resolve any ambiguity. The problem is that sometimes the package names has a meaning (e.g. `Tools.Useless.Foo` and `Tools.Useful.Foo`).

Comment: Basically you never use `import anything.*` because the result is *too many* imports in most cases.

Comment: If you have classes with the same name, you normally import one with `import path.withsame.Name` on the first one and then you have to use the long `path.tonamed.Thing` on every other reference.  Yes using more unique names on the classes themselves will help.

Comment: Other than that, I think you've got it figured out.  Java has some limitations due to a desire for "simplicity" that sometimes trip people up, but you get used to them after a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java packages are not nested. While their names may have common prefixes, that has no meaning within the Java programming language.

Also the fact that their class files are stored in nested directories when the storage is a file system, has no additional meaning. When classes are stored in a jar file, they are stored with entry names matching their qualified names without actually forming directories at all (though a lot of tools like to present them as-if being in a hierarchical structure to mimic a file system).

So the packages `com.company.project.tools.useless` and `com.company.project.tools` have no relationship at all. While we humans tend to organize code in such a way, that a semantic relationship can be assumed here (which is a good thing), there is none on a technical level. There is no relative addressing between them and there are no additional access rights, compared to any other two packages. In fact, both packages could be part of two different modules (starting with Java 9), with even less access permission compared to two other packages with less similar names.

The standard approach to use the class from another package, is to use `import com.company.project.Tools.Useless.Foo;`, followed by using `Foo` within the class.

It’s not quiet clear, which problem you see with that, i.e. what “since importing it will bind it to the current scope” is supposed to mean. The mere existence of an `import` statement, has no effect on the code. All it tells the compiler, is how to resolve occurrences of the simple name `Foo`, if no other `Foo` is in scope.

In other words, local scopes still have precedence, even including inherited members. Further, at places where variables and types could appear, variables have precedence. E.g. for an occurrence of `Foo.bar()`, a variable called `Foo` would have precedence, a local variable before member variables within the same type, an outer class or inherited ones. Otherwise, member types, outer types or inherited member types would be used. Only if none of them exist, the `import` statement would be used to resolve `Foo`.

Needless to say, you should avoid having so many items with the same simple name that you would have to think about the details of the resolving process. That’s why the naming conventions suggest to start variable names with a lowercase letter and class names with an upper case letter.

And yes, avoid giving classes the same simple name. Once you have to deal with both classes within the same compilation unit, there is no way around accessing one of them with its (fully¹) qualified name throughout the entire compilation unit. (Using a `*` in import doesn’t help you in any way with such a scenario)

---

As explained, the term “fully” is obsolete in Java, as qualified names are always complete.

Comment: "When classes are stored in a jar file, they are stored with entry names matching their qualified names without actually forming directories at all". Could you explain this more? When I open a jar file, it has a directory structure for the class files.

Comment: @Lilypad a jar file is an extended zip file, which just stores a linear sequence of entries. Such a file could consist of a single entry containing the file `java/lang/Object.class`. The directory structure you see when opening the file is generated by the tool you use for opening. It will deduce from the file name `java/lang/Object.class` that it should show you a directory `java` containing a directory `lang` containing a file `Object.class`. This is the same structure that tools will (usually) generate when extracting the file. The true structure is what you get with `JarInputStream`.